# Should I use Databinding to put data on my web page?

Tags: asp.net

[A video tutorial](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-08.aspx) says I should use databinding to put data on my webpage. Is this the right thing to do?

It feels wrong to do it. Shouldn't there be a separation of concerns? The view should be separated from the code that connects to the database? In the aforementioned video, he connects to the database without going through a data access layer. What about the presenter/controller? It seems like we are completely bypassing those layers, going around the architecture.

Comment: All of the other questions get answers without mocking up a silly title :)

Comment: @Shog9: I assume that was for me...sorry about that. After Jonathan's edit to make this a more legitimately worded question my comment was unecessary (and incorrect). For the record, my original comment was something like this: "If this is a serious question, it should be worded as such."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to realise that, when Microsoft produce a new UI technology, at least 2/3rds of it is designed to make it easy for newbies to slap together very simple 2-tier demo apps. I'm not saying this is a bad thing - after all, it helps us get up to speed on the technology quickly. However, when you are writing a proper n-tier app, then it's important to know which bits of the technology can and cannot be used.

For example, in ASP.NET WebForms, you should voluntarily restrict yourself as follows:

- Don't use any data source control except for `ObjectDataSource`, and only use that for binding the Model to the View.
- Don't use validation controls to validate input controls. Instead, pass all data to the Business Layer for validation and just display the resulting error messages on screen.
- Don't use the built-in sorting/filtering/paging functions of the `GridView`. Instead, implement your own sorting/filtering/paging mechanism in the Business Layer.

To answer your original question: yes, data binding is very useful, as long as you bind to the Presentation Layer Model, rather than to a real data source.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan, you're thinking about ASP.NET MVC, whereas that tutorial is written for ASP.NET (which MVC developers like to refer to as ASP.NET Webforms). Have a look at the ASP.NET MVC tutorials here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/learn/

Keep in mind that although both have ASP.NET in the name, they're completely different programming philosophies. Webforms tries to mimic a stateful, event-driven form, like a Winform application. MVC, on the other hand, seperates it into models, views, and controllers, which fits very well with the web's stateless and request/response cycle.

Comment: MedicineMan asked the question - and just because the framework encourages it doesn't make it right.